# Set condition country base on woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing a woocommerce plugin and trying to set a condition that it will work when a specific country selected. My code is below. But i'm unable to get the shipping country and its not working. Please have a look what wrong i've done. My target is to work this plugin when the country === australia only. But its working for every country.

```
<?php

    class WC_Australia_Post_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method{
      public function __construct(){


  $this->id = 'australia_post_shipping_method';
  $this->method_title = __( 'Australia Post Shipping Method', 'woocommerce' );
  // Load the settings.
  $this->init_form_fields();
  $this->init_settings();
  // Define user set variables
  $this->enabled  = $this->get_option( 'enabled' );
  $this->title     = $this->get_option( 'title' );


  add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );


}
      public function init_form_fields(){

  $this->form_fields = array(
    'enabled' => array(
      'title'     => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce' ),
      'type'       => 'checkbox',
      'label'     => __( 'Enable Australia Post Shipping', 'woocommerce' ),
      'default'     => 'yes'
    ),
    'title' => array(
      'title'     => __( 'Method Title', 'woocommerce' ),
      'type'       => 'text',
      'description'   => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ),
      'default'    => __( 'Australia Post Shipping', 'woocommerce' ),

    )
  );


}
      public function is_available( $package ){

      $country= $package[‘destination’][‘country’];
      if($country =='Australia'){
      return false;

       }
  return true;

}
      public function calculate_shipping($package){

      $cost=190;

    // send the final rate to the user. 
    $this->add_rate( array(
      'id'   => $this->id,
      'label' => $this->title,
      'cost'   => $cost
    ));



}
    }

?>
```